# How to read last N number of last days from the current date in parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have saved the data in warehouse in parquet file format with partition by date type column.

I try to get last N days data from the current date using scala spark.

The file data in saved like as below as warehouse path.

```
Tespath/filename/dt=2020-02-01
Tespath/filename/dt=2020-02-02
...........
Tespath/filename/dt=2020-02-28
```

If i read all the data its very hug amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your dataset is correctly partitioned using the parquet format, you just need to read the directory `Testpath/filename` and let Spark do the partition discovery.

It will add a `dt` column in your schema with the value from the path name : `dt=<value>`.This value can be used to filter your dataset and Spark will optimize the read by partition pruning all directory which does not match you predicate on the `dt` column.
You could try something like this :

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.functions._

val df = spark.read.parquet("Testpath/filename/")
  .where($"dt" > date_sub(current_date(), N))
```

You need to ensure `spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown` is set to true (which is default)